# maven jar deployed twice in a war module with attachClasses set to true

Tags: maven, maven-3, war, nexus

I am trying to use module as a dependency in another project by deploying it to our nexus repository.
The problem is that maven tries to deploy the jar twice and our policy forbids to overwrite a release version.
The module is packaged as a war.
Here is my configuration.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-war</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>war</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

When I set attachClasses to false, everything goes fine and the war gets deployed, but the jar doesn't.
When I set it to true, the jar gets deployed but maven tries to deploy a second time and then the build fails.
Any idea why maven tries to deploy it twice.
(The module has a parent module, but it does not depend on any other module from the project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that you defined your own execution.

Try to remove the block

```
           <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-war</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>war</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
```