# maven-war-plugin: jar deployed twice in nexus when attachClasses set to true

Tags: java, maven, nexus, maven-war-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin

I have a very similar problem as exposed in [maven jar deployed twice in a war module with attachClasses set to true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59376513/maven-jar-deployed-twice-in-a-war-module-with-attachclasses-set-to-true), except that my setting is different and that what seems to have helped, doesn't work for me this time.

Here my setting:

- one multimodule with 2 projects, A and B, with B depending on A
- since A is primarily packaging a WAR, I configured the war-plugin by setting attachClasses to true, so that a classes.jar file is generated which makes possible for B to depend on A ([see here for more on this](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#attachClasses))

```xml
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                       <manifestEntries><Build-Time>${maven.build.timestamp}</Build-Time></manifestEntries>-->
                    </archive>
                    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

All works fine except that when Jenkins tries to deploy on Nexus, it tries to deploy the file classes.jar twice which leads to a failure.

Has someone a clue?

Answer (score 1):

The architecture of the multi module project is suboptimal.

Extract the classes that both A and B need into a new module C and let A and B depend on C. Avoid to use side artifacts as dependencies.

Comment: This is a legacy project and I unfortunately I can't change the architecture, so I'm looking for a workarround

Comment: If you can't change then you can't fix the issue... you must change something..